# How does NServiceBus handle transactions?

Tags: nservicebus

Does NServiceBus automatically attempt to redeliver messages if handling fails? And if it does, is there a limit in the number of times delivery can be attempted?

Answer (score 3):

NSB will enlist in a distributed transaction and if it fails it will retry the configured number of times.  Look at the MsmqTransport config section.

EDIT: A distributed transaction begins as soon as you peek or receive a message from MSMQ.  All of the work you do in a message handler will be included in the transaction and it is governed by the [Distributed Transaction Coordinator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_Transaction_Coordinator).  The DTC will also include things like DB transactions if you are updating DBs and so on.

If say a DB update fails, the whole thing rolls back and the message is put back on the queue.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what NSB considers a 'distributed transaction'? For example, ActiveMQ can wrap all incoming and outgoing messages in a single session which is transactional.